# How to verify login.live.com SSL certificate with cURL, PHP and Windows XAMPP

Tags: php, windows, curl, https, xampp

I need to make a HTTP request to `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf` with cURL in PHP. cURL always gives the following error message: `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` (error no 60). This is my **setup**:

- Apache Friends XAMPP v5.6.3 on Windows 7 64-bit (no configuration changes); this includes:
- PHP 5.6.3
- cURL 7.39.0
- OpenSSL/1.0.1i

I included the [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) file from the [cURL CA Extract](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) website with the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option. This file includes the `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` certificate. This certificate is identical to the root certificate which Firefox displays for `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf`.

This is my **test PHP script**:

```php
<?php

// $url = 'https://api.onedrive.com';
$url = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf';

$ch = curl_init($url);

$errorLog = fopen('php://temp', 'rw');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $errorLog);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'ca-bundle.crt');

curl_exec($ch);

$error = curl_error($ch);
if ($error != '') {
  echo "### cURL error: ###\n";
  echo curl_errno($ch) . ' ' . curl_error($ch) . "\n\n";
}

curl_close($ch);

echo "### cURL verbose output: ###\n";
rewind($errorLog);
echo stream_get_contents($errorLog);
```

It generates the following **output**:

```
### cURL error: ###
60 SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

### cURL verbose output: ###
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 131.253.61.98...
* Connected to login.live.com (131.253.61.98) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

I tested **another URL**, `https://api.onedrive.com`. According to Firefox this site's root certificate is the `Baltimore CyberTrust Root` certificate, which also is included in the [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) file. For this URL cURL works as expected and the script generates the following **output**:

```
### cURL verbose output: ###
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.onedrive.com/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 134.170.106.24...
* Connected to api.onedrive.com (134.170.106.24) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=WA; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft Corporation; CN=storage.live.com
*    start date: 2015-03-03 21:28:09 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-03-02 21:28:09 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.onedrive.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation; OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.onedrive.com
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 264
< Content-Type: application/json
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
< X-MSNSERVER: BN1305____PAP241
< X-QosStats: {"ApiId":0,"ResultType":2,"SourcePropertyId":0,"TargetPropertyId":42}
< X-ThrowSite: 7ecf.1484
< X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 19.15.0.0
< Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2015 17:34:56 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.onedrive.com left intact
```

I also exported the `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` certificate from `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf` with Firefox and used that certificate instead of the [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) file. I also added the intermediate certificate `VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA`. Both did not help.

How can I verify the login.live.com SSL certificate with the given setup? Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` is not what I am looking for.

**UPDATE:** I did some more research and now it looks like this [might be an OpenSSL issue on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111438/openssl-s-client-certificate-validation-fails-in-windows-for-login-live-com).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The short answer is: Use [VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA certificate with serial number 3c 91 31 cb 1f f6 d0 1b 0e 9a b8 d0 44 bf 12 be](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority.pem) which is linked on [Symantec's website](http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=roots) (Root 2) to validate `login.live.com:443` with cURL/OpenSSL in Windows. In Linux this certificate will probably be preinstalled in a way OpenSSL can use (and will use even if you supply a certificate file with `CURLOPT_CAINFO`).

The longer answer is: cURL uses OpenSSL for HTTPs connections. Current OpenSSL versions won't validate a chain of certificates where a root certificate is trusted but is signed by another untrusted root certificate. This is true for the [VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 certificate](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem) which is correctly displayed by Firefox as a root certificate for `login.live.com:443` and which is included in [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt). This root certificate is again signed by the above mentioned [VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA certificate](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/Class-3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority.pem). If this last mentioned root certificate is not known as a trusted root certificate to OpenSSL, validation of the certificate chain fails.

I found this information

- in the [answer to my question s_client certificate validation fails in Windows for login.live.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29115499/846987),
- in the article [Supporting trusted but untrusted certificates with OpenSSL](http://kriscience.blogspot.de/2013/03/supporting-trusted-but-untrusted.html) linked in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111438/s-client-certificate-validation-fails-in-windows-for-login-live-com#comment46480473_29115499) to that answer and
- in the article [Fixing VeriSign Certificates on Windows Servers](http://www.confusedamused.com/notebook/fixing-verisign-certificates-on-windows-servers/) linked in the first article.