# s_client certificate validation fails in Windows for login.live.com

Tags: windows, ssl, https, openssl

I downloaded [Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2.exe](http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2.exe) from [Shining Light Productions](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and installed it to the default location `C:\OpenSSL-Win32`. I copied the file [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) to `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin` and ran:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl s_client -connect login.live.com:443 -CAfile ca-bundle.crt
```

The verification of the certificate chain fails with the message:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Using the same command with the same [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt) file on Debian Wheezy with OpenSSL version 1.0.1e returns:

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

If I change the hostname to `api.onedrive.com` (same command) I get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)` on both, Windows and Linux.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a known bug? How can i get it to work on Windows for `login.live.com`?

(Initially I stumbled upon this problem when [trying to connect to login.live.com with PHP's cURL extension under Windows XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106240/how-to-verify-login-live-com-ssl-certificate-with-curl-php-and-windows-xampp), but now it looks more like an OpenSSL issue.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s_client` has the undocumented property (or probably more a long standing bug), that if you give a `-CAfile` option it will not only check against the given CA file but also against the systems default (`/usr/lib/ssl/certs` on Debian).  If you run `openssl s_client` with `strace` to check out which files are used during the verification you will see the following:

```
$ strace -e open openssl s_client -connect login.live.com:443 -CAfile ca-bundle.crt
...
open("ca-bundle.crt", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/ssl/certs/415660c1.0", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/ssl/certs/415660c1.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

From this output you can see that it not only uses the given CA file for verification but also tries to use `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem` (does not exist) and then looks into `/usr/lib/ssl/certs` to find the required CA by the subject hash `415660c1`. There it finally finds the root CA it is looking for in `415660c1.1`:

```
 $ openssl x509 -in /usr/lib/ssl/certs/415660c1.1 -text
 ...
 Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
 ...
 Subject: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
```

Since there are no system defaults on Windows usable by OpenSSL (it can not use the Windows CA store) the verification will fail there.

As for `api.onedrive.com`: this has another trust chain and can fully be verified with the given CA bundle. The output from `strace` shows that it does not try to access any files inside `/usr/lib/ssl/certs`.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my initial question! However there are two more things which I don't understand: (1) Both certificates, `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority` (415660c1.0) and `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority 2`  (415660c1.1) validate the connection to login.live.com with s_client in Windows. Why do both work? (2) Firefox shows `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` as root certificate for login.live.com. Exporting this certificate and supplying it to s_client does not validate the connection. Why not?

Comment: Both these certificates have the same subject and thus the same subject hash. But they have different public keys and only one of these keys can be used to verify the trust chain.

Comment: And is for the other question, why the G5 authority can not be used to validate login.live.com... This is a long and ugly story and at the end what I consider a bug with OpenSSL. For details see http://kriscience.blogspot.de/2013/03/supporting-trusted-but-untrusted.html

Comment: Thank's again, that was really enlightening! About `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority` (415660c1.0) and `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority 2` (415660c1.1) both validating the connection to login.live.com: Is the reason that `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5` is signed by both of them?

Comment: You are right. Both certificates contain the same public key and thus can be used to validate the certificate. They are in effect the same certificates (even same life time) but differ in the hash algorithm. 415660c1.0 uses md2 which is probably no longer acceptable and thus  415660c1.1 (with sha1) will be used instead.